# How can get the manufactory, model details of a photo?

Tags: android

Normally, I can use the following code to get the details such as path, size ,date of a photo.
but the other details of a photo such as  manufactory, model can't be found, how can I do? Thanks!

```
String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN
    };

    // Get the base URI for the People table in the Contacts content provider.
    Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    // Make the query.
    Cursor cur = managedQuery(images,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            "",         // Which rows to return (all rows)
            null,       // Selection arguments (none)
            ""          // Ordering
            );

    Log.i("ListingImages"," query count="+cur.getCount());

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        String bucket;
        String date;
        int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

        int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);

        do {
            // Get the field values
            bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);
            date = cur.getString(dateColumn);

            // Do something with the values.
            Log.i("ListingImages", " bucket=" + bucket 
                   + "  date_taken=" + date);
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ExifInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) to get information about picture.

It includes: `TAG_MAKE` and `TAG_MODEL`

```
    try {
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface("file path");
        String make = ei.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE);
        String model = ei.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is written in photo's [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format).

You can use [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) class to get needed data.

`TAG_MODEL` and `TAG_MAKE` is that what is interesting you.